# Unable to start Selenium Safari WebDriver via python3

Tags: python, selenium, safari, safaridriver

I want to use Safari as the browser from python, and the code is fairly easy:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Safari()
url = 'https://www.gmail.com/'
driver.get(url)
```

I am using the latest version of Safari, 11.0.3,

In preferences-extension, I have WebDriver installed,

In develop on menu, I have "allow Remote Automation" enabled.

I'm using python 3.5, selenium 3.10.0

While running the code above, I got the following Error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/hwang/Documents/Lumi_personal/Coding/sandbox/testSelenium.py", line 2, in <module>
driver = webdriver.Safari()

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/safari/webdriver.py", line 49, in __init__
self.service.start()

AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'service'
```

Any help is appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just to rule it out -- have you tried passing in the actual path to your web driver in the instantiation?  driver = webdriver.Safari("/path/to/safaridriver").

Comment: @SteveJ thanks for the comment, I tried passing the Path, and unfortunately it didn't help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the same issue with selenium 3.10, but not with 3.9.

Apparently, there's a bug in version 3.10 according to: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/5578

My temporary solution is to uninstall selenium 3.10, and install 3.9:

```
pip uninstall selenium
pip install selenium==3.9
```

And it should solve the problem.

Comment: I have selenium 3.11. It did not with safari 11 either. Selenium 3.9 works.

Comment: Thanks!  And, of course, this also fixes the same issue with Robot Framework.

Answer (score 0):

You can also "patch" Safari webdriver by adding line 25 and 49
https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/commit/2a0f63d19bd6e666ad432ee459762489d6b6033a

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried, but it didn't help. Still same result.